# Adding View dynamically to RelativeLayout not working

Tags: java, android, imageview, android-relativelayout

I am working on an app where I need to extensively work with animations. My problem is, I added an some ImageViews to my RelativeLayout through Java. But next to that when I am trying to add another ImageView applying rules like BELOW,ALIGN_LEFT etc with respect to previously added views, those images don't show up. It's annoying :( primarily, my question is, do these rules(LEFT,RIGHT_OF,BELOW etc) work with respect to already dynamically added views?

Comment: Yes, provided the previous `View`s have valid IDs.

Comment: that means if I haven't set the IDs of those ImageView'S' explicitly, it shouldn't work, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q : do these rules(LEFT,RIGHT_OF,BELOW etc) work with respect to already dynamically added view

Ans: **Yes they were much work.** Sample Code

```
RelativeLayout rLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rlayout);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lprams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
Button tv1 = new Button(this);
tv1.setText("Hello");
tv1.setLayoutParams(lprams);
tv1.setId(1);
rLayout.addView(tv1);

// second Button
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams newParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
Button tv2 = new Button(this);
tv1.setText("Hello2");
newParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, 1);
tv2.setLayoutParams(newParams);
tv2.setId(2);
rLayout.addView(tv2);
```

You need to set Ids and then give Whatever RULE you want to add for that view.

Comment: thank you very much :)  I found my error ! I was not setting the IDs of those ImageViews. Stupid me :p

Comment: You are welcome.. If this helped you please upvote and accept the answer.